# Avoiding duplicates options_for_select during editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a form where users can edit previously input data, some of this data comes from selection boxes on the new form. In the edit form these same fields are selects again and to avoid overwriting the current value I'm passing it in as an option. (As below)

```
<%= f.select :ldn, options_for_select([[@subcontractor.ldn], ["No"], ["Yes"]]) %>
```

The result of this is that the selection box has three options two of which are duplicates.

[image: Example]

Can anyone advise a decent solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

```
<%= f.select :ldn, options_for_select(["No", "Yes"],@subcontractor.ldn)  %>
```

Comment: Actually I've just tried it with a few others and it seems to not be working as hoped [example](http://cl.ly/image/38072J2t2u0z)